# Can't leave loop

Tags: c, loops, goto

I created small code in C to test something. I thought that if i write 0 I will receive output ABC. But I cannot leave the loop. Please help me. Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int x;

while(1)
    {
    printf("Enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x=0)
        goto stop;
    }

stop:
    printf("ABC");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(x=0)` is assigning, not comparing.  Also, don't `goto stop;`... just `break;`.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` in your `if`

Comment: please don't use `goto`, you can just `break` out of the loop

Comment: You should test the result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
     if(x=0)
```

to

```
     if (x==0)
```

Originally you were assigning 0 to x, but you want to compare. To compare x with 0 you need to use ==

Comment: ya might consider telling him why.

Comment: BTW, if you enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler, you would be warned with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 2):

the code is wrong
the code

if(x = 0 )

should change to

if(x == 0 )

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out, a single equal sign in c is assignment, and a double equals sign tests for equality. In this case, the double equals sign is needed. So instead of 
        if(x = 0), you want if(x == 0)
One more tip, using break is preferable to a goto statement here.
Hope this helps.